# Mobius Transformation Sum of Series

Tags: complex-analysis

Do there exists any Mobius transformation where $f(z)$ is the sum of the series
 $\sum_{n≥2} (2z − i)^n$ for all $z$ such that $|2z − i|$ < $\frac12$?

Comment: This is unclear but you know $\sum_{n≥2} w^n=\dfrac{w^2}{1-w}$.

Answer (score 0):

**One possible suggestion:** You can approach this problem using Perron's formula. I'm assuming that by Moebius transform of the function $f(z)$ you mean that you want 
$$\mathcal{M}[f](z) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \left(\sum_{d|n} [x^d] f(x) \mu(n/d)\right) z^n.$$
Let's work out the problem for the simpler case where $$g(z) = \sum_{n \geq 0} (2z-i)^n = \frac{1}{1+\imath} \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{2^n}{(1+\imath)^n} z^n, $$
so that 
$$\mathcal{M}[g](z) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \sum_{d|n}  \frac{2^d}{(1+\imath)^d} \mu(n/d) \cdot z^n.$$ 
(*Perhaps this needs some clarification since this is what I think of when I hear Moebius transform.*)
Then since the DGF of the coefficients in the transform of this function is given by $\operatorname{Li}_s(2 / (1+\imath)) / \zeta(s)$, by [Perron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%27s_formula) we have that 
$$[z^n] \mathcal{M}[g](z) = \frac{1}{2\pi\imath} \int_{c-\imath\infty}^{c+\imath\infty} \frac{\operatorname{Li}_s\left(\frac{2}{1+\imath}\right)}{s \zeta(s)} n^s ds.$$ 
Note that this is where the solution gets iffy. If my complex analysis skills are still sharp, we can choose $c = 1/2$ and sum over the non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function to obtain that 
$$[z^n] \mathcal{M}[g](z)/(1-z) = \sum_{\gamma: \zeta(1/2+\imath\gamma) = 0} \frac{\operatorname{Li}_{1/2+\imath\gamma}\left(\frac{2}{1+\imath}\right)}{(1/2+\imath\gamma) \zeta^{\prime}(1/2+\imath\gamma)}.$$
Another approach to finding exact expressions for the average order of the coefficients of the transformed function is to use [these identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_sum_identities#Interchange_of_summation_identities) and [this form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%27s_formula#Generalizations) of Perron's formula to sum in terms of the [Mertens function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_function) as follows:
$$\sum_{n=1}^x \sum_{d|n} c^d \mu(n/d) = \sum_{d=1}^x c^d M(\lfloor x/d \rfloor).$$